# Proving one of the canonical Hamilton equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I have a homework question asking me to prove that $\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial t}$, and the hint is to first consider a system with one degree of freedom where the equation for the Hamiltonian simplifies to $\mathcal{H}(q,p,t)=p\dot{q}(q,p,t)-\mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q}(q,p,t),t)$. Now I tried to take the partial derivative with respect to time but I'm not sure that I'm doing it right, for my first step I get $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial t}=p\frac{\partial \dot{q}(q,p,t)}{\partial t}\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q}(q,p,t),t)}{\partial t}\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \dot{q}(q,p,t)}{\partial t}\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}$$
I'll spare you the details of simplifying, but I get stuck at $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\partial ^2q}{\partial t^2}\frac{\partial\dot{q}}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\Big)$$
So in theory, the stuff in the parenthesis should equal one if I'm doing this right, but I'm unsure if I am. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The dimensions in your last expression don't seem to be right; can you go back and carefully check dimensions at every step?

Comment: What do you mean by the dimensions don't seem to be right?

Comment: What @knzhou means is that if you look at the terms inside the parentheses, then the space and time dimensions don't match. The first term is $L^2T^{-4}$, while the second term is $LT^{-1}$. I am sure if you check for errors you will arrive at the right answer.

Comment: Oh ok, turns out I forgot a two in the exponent of the denominator of the term on the left, but I do see what you mean.

Comment: Also does that mean the first step appears to be correct?

Comment: You should treat $p$, $q$ and $t$ as independent.

Comment: So $\mathcal{L}$ and $\dot{q}$ are the only things that I need to differentiate with respect to time?

Answer (score 1):

Your opening non inline equation is also incorrect on dimensional grounds, the first factor by $LT^{-1}$ and the second by $L^3 T^{-4}$.

For a one dimensional system as you are considering here, $H=H(q,p,t)$,  and so one has $$dH = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}dp + \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}dt\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ generically.

From the explicit realisation of the hamiltonian function as a legendre transform of the lagrangian, as you have written in your question, we also find $$dH = p \,d \dot{q} + dp \, \dot q - \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}d \dot q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}dt\right) $$

This can be simplified in favour of writing the single  generalised momenta  in terms of the generalised velocity $p = \partial L/\partial \dot q$ to obtain $$dH = dp \, \dot q - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}dq - \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}dt\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ will give you your desired relation, in addition to two other equations which collectively comprise *Hamilton's equations*.

You can also proceed more directly using your legendre transform. Since there is explicit and implicit instances of $t$ in the legendre transform, it is fruitful to extract a total derivative of $H$ with respect to $t$. So, $$\frac{d H}{dt} = p \frac{d \dot q}{dt} - \frac{dL}{dt} = p \frac{d \dot q}{dt} - \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} \frac{d \dot q}{dt} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \right) = -\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}.$$

Using $(1)$ together with the Hamilton's equations, you find in fact $dH/dt = \partial H/\partial t$ obtaining again $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$$

Comment: This helped me figure it out, I eventually got it. Turns out I didn't do chain rule properly, once I fixed that the problem worked itself out fairly easily. Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) if you feel your question has been answered please accept my answer to close the issue.