# How to prove that $dh/dt = ∂h/∂t$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism

We already know that the energy function $h(q,\dot{q},t)$ (not the Hamiltonian!) in classical mechanics follows the equation $dh/dt = −∂L/∂t$ but how can we show that $dh/dt = ∂h/∂t$ is also true?

Answer (score 1):

In Lagrangian mechanics (as opposed to Hamiltonian mechanics), we calculate:
$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}-\frac{d h}{d t}  ~\stackrel{\text{EL eqs.}}{\approx}~\frac{\partial (h+L)}{\partial t}~=~\frac{\partial (\dot{q}^ip_i)}{\partial t}~=~\dot{q}^i\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial t~\partial \dot{q}^i}. $$
There is no generic reason why this should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

This can simply follow from writing down the total derivative $\text{d}h/\text{d}t$, where $h=h(q,p,t)$, with the imposition of Hamilton’s equations.

See e.g [Proving one of the canonical Hamilton equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380198/proving-one-of-the-canonical-hamilton-equations/380260#380260) for more elaborate discussion.

Comment: I am grateful for your guidance. However that works with Hamiltonian and when we are in phase space but what i am looking for is a solution or a hint for solving it in configuration space where p=p(q,q˙,t).

Answer (score 0):

You write down the total derivative for $\dfrac{dH}{dt}$, then replace the partials via Hamilton's equations:

$$
\dfrac{dH}{dt} = \Sigma_i\Big(\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\dfrac{dp_i}{dt}-\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}\dfrac{dq_i}{dt}\Big) - \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial t}
$$
Insert Hamilton's equations: $\dot q_i = \partial H/ \partial p_i$, $ \dot p_i = -\partial H/\partial q_i$
$$
\dfrac{dH}{dt} = \Sigma_i\Big(\dot q_i\dot p_i - \dot p_i \dot q_i\Big) - \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\dfrac{dH}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial t}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your work but i don't wanna interfere Hamiltonian or cannonical equations in any way.